# DELETE methods seems to do nothing

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, routes

I got two routes to same template with different http methods:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GetPostToShow",
    template: "posts",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetPostToShow" },
    constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodRouteConstraint(new string[] { "GET" }) });
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DeletePost",
    template: "posts",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "DeletePost" },
    constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodRouteConstraint(new string[] { "DELETE" }) });
```

Both actions get same query parameter and return different views

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPostToEdit(int postId)
    ...//load post from database and send it to view
    return View("EditPost", post);

public async Task<IActionResult> DeletePost(int postId)
    ...//locate post in database and remove it, redir to Index then
    return RedirectToAction("GetIndex");
```

And DELETE method implemented in form(antiforgery turned off cause of testing):

```html
<form asp-antiforgery="false" method="delete" role="form">
    <input hidden type="number" name="postId" value="@Model.Id"/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

So when I'm submit this form I expect got redirected to my Index page or error message to show, but nothing really happens. It seems like it just reloads the page. What I can do so it will work properly?

**UPDATE**:
I googled and found that *DELETE* not meant to be used in forms. Of course I can just create `@Html.RouteLink` redirect, but I still want to get use of *DELETE* method. How can I create button which give request with that method?

Comment: Redirect won't help you, browser follow redirects with a GET. And yes, Verb can't be sent via froms. Only JavaScript/Ajax or via http client (when calling from an application and not from a browser, i.e. nodejs/c#/java/c++ etc)

Comment: Here you have some info related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114156/why-are-there-are-no-put-and-delete-methods-on-html-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've determined, HTML forms only support GET and POST, not DELETE or any of the other HTTP verbs. If you want to send via DELETE, your only choice is making an AJAX request instead.

You'd simply bind a handler to the submit event of the form, call `event.preventDefault()`, to prevent the normal form submit, and then send the request via AJAX instead:

```
document.getElementById('#myForm').addEventHandler('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // send via AJAX with DELETE as the method
});
```